# R add column where cell values based on values in a different row

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` where each row says whether an animal was found in a particular location.

I want to create a new column in this example `data.frame` that is labeled `"prey"`. This value will be a 1 or a 0 depending on if a predator's prey was found in the same location (each location has a unique `ID`).

The problem is each animal has a separate row, so the information about prey presence in a different row from the predator. The two predators are lions and cheetahs.

For this example lion's prey are antelope and zebra, so:

- For `ID` 1, since antelope and lions were found in that location, the prey column should have a 1 in the row for lion.
- For `ID` 2, no antelope or zebra were found so the the prey column for the lion row would be 0.

Cheetahs prey are antelope, gazelle, impala.

Below is the example `data.frame` and a solution I came up with that is very inefficient and I'm looking for something faster/tidier.

```
 df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,1,1,1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
             species=c("lion", "antelope", "zebra", "cheetah", "impala", "gazelles", "lion", "antelope", "zebra", "cheetah", "impala", "gazelles"),
             present=c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

k=list(list())
for (i in 1:2) { ### for loop ofr 2 unique IDs
k[[i]]=df[which(df$ID == unique(df$ID[i])),]
k[[i]]$antelope=0
k[[i]]$zebra=0
k[[i]]$impala=0
k[[i]]$gazelle=0
k[[i]]$lionprey=0
k[[i]]$cheetahprey=0

k[[i]]$antelope[[1]]=ifelse(k[[i]]$pres[[2]]==1, 1, 0)
k[[i]]$zebra[[1]]=ifelse(k[[i]]$pres[[3]]==1, 1, 0)
k[[i]]$lionprey[[1]]=ifelse (k[[i]]$antelope[[1]] == 1 || 
k[[i]]$zebra[[1]] == 1, 1, 0) 

k[[i]]$antelope[[4]]=ifelse(k[[i]]$pres[[2]]==1, 1, 0)
k[[i]]$gazelle[[4]]=ifelse(k[[i]]$pres[[6]]==1, 1, 0)
k[[i]]$impala[[4]]=ifelse(k[[i]]$pres[[5]]==1, 1, 0)
k[[i]]$cheetahprey[[4]]= ifelse(k[[i]]$antelope[[4]] == 1 || 
k[[i]]$gazelle[[4]] == 1 || k[[i]]$impala[[4]]==1, 1, 0) 

}

k=do.call("rbind", k)
k$antelope=NULL
k$zebra=NULL
k$impala=NULL
k$gazelle=NULL
k$prey=k$lionprey+k$cheetahprey
k$lionprey=NULL
k$cheetahprey=NULL
```

Comment: if you don't get good answers, think about simplifying this more and also adding the desired output.

Comment: Your data uses `"gazelles"` and your code uses `"gazelle"`. I'd use `"gazelle"` throughout if it was up to me (though in my answer below, i used your data as you posted it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the reasons you describe, this involves some messy logical expressions, but here's one way to do it. This has the benefit of being generalizable. If you want to add predators, just add them to `predators` and add their prey to `predators_prey` accordingly. `predators_prey` is a list to accommodate for (as occurs here) predators with differing number of prey:

```
# define the predators
predators <- c("lion", "cheetah")

# create a list of their prey from which to programmatically extract
predators_prey <- list(lion = c("antelope", "zebra"), cheetah = c("antelope", "gazelles", "impala"))

# initialize the $prey column
df$prey <- 0

# use for loop because we're assigning a value in global env
for (predator in predators ){
  for (ID in unique(df$ID)){

    # is the predator here?
    predator_here = df[df$ID == ID & df$species == predator,]$present
    # is that predator's prey here?
    prey_here = any(df[df$ID == ID & df$present == 1,]$species %in% predators_prey[[predator]])

    # if both, then set $prey to 1
    if(predator_here & prey_here){
      df[df$ID == ID & df$species == predator,]$prey <- 1
    }
  }
}
# lets look at the result
df
#    ID  species present prey
# 1   1     lion       1    1
# 2   1 antelope       1    0
# 3   1    zebra       0    0
# 4   1  cheetah       1    1
# 5   1   impala       1    0
# 6   1 gazelles       0    0
# 7   2     lion       1    0
# 8   2 antelope       0    0
# 9   2    zebra       0    0
# 10  2  cheetah       1    1
# 11  2   impala       1    0
# 12  2 gazelles       1    0
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,1,1,1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                 species=c("lion", "antelope", "zebra", "cheetah", "impala", "gazelles", "lion", "antelope", "zebra", "cheetah", "impala", "gazelles"),
                 present=c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `tidyr::spread` to simplify the structure of your first data frame.

```
df <- df %>% spread(species, present)

#>   ID antelope cheetah gazelles impala lion zebra
#>1   1        1       1        0      1    1     0
#>2   2        0       1        1      1    1     0
```

Then continue with `dplyr`.

```
df %>% 
  spread(species, present) %>%
  mutate(lion_prey = case_when(antelope == 1 | zebra == 1 ~ 1,
                               TRUE ~ 0),
         cheetah_prey = case_when(antelope == 1 | gazelles == 1  | impala == 1 ~ 1,
                               TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  gather(species, present, -ID, -lion_prey, -cheetah_prey) %>%
  mutate(prey = case_when(species == "lion" ~ lion_prey,
                          species == "cheetah" ~ cheetah_prey,
                          TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  select(-lion_prey, -cheetah_prey)

#>       ID  species present prey
#>    1   1 antelope       1    0
#>    2   2 antelope       0    0
#>    3   1  cheetah       1    1
#>    4   2  cheetah       1    1
#>    5   1 gazelles       0    0
#>    6   2 gazelles       1    0
#>    7   1   impala       1    0
#>    8   2   impala       1    0
#>    9   1     lion       1    1
#>    10  2     lion       1    0
#>    11  1    zebra       0    0
#>    12  2    zebra       0    0
```